# Replace values in R, "Yes" to 1 and "No" to 0

Tags: r, dataset

I am working with weatherAUS dataset that is avaiable in the R libraries. I am trying to replace "Yes" to 1 and "No" to 0 in the RainTomorrow column.

I wrote this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
weather4$RainTomorrow[weather4$RainTomorrow=="Yes"]<-1
```

I just says:

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, weather4$RainTomorrow ==
>   "Yes", value = c(NA,  :   invalid factor level, NA generated

What does it mean and what should I do? I reckon I should use as.numeric or as.factor somewhere but I don't know how really.

Comment: Just do `as.integer(as.character(weather$RainTomorrow)=="Yes")`

Comment: No, just keep it as it is. Why do you believe 0/1 is needed instead of a factor variable?

Comment: Hi guys. See my post below. I just solved the problem.

Answer (score 16):

You can easily do this with dplyr.

```
require(dplyr)
weather4 <- weather4 %>%
      mutate(RainToday = ifelse(RainToday == "No",0,1))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

```
library(data.table)   
weather4[,":="(RainTomorrow=ifelse(RainTomorrow=="no",0,1))]
```

or simply use:

```
as.numeric(as.factor(weather4$RainTomorrow))
```

Comment: Don't use ifelse in data.table. It's inefficient. Use a join or simple subsetting. However, I don't see why data.table is needed if OP isn't already using it.

Comment: @Roland how about as.numeric(as.factor(weather4$RainTomorrow)), I test it on my side, it is more efficient compare with ifelse.

Answer (score 4):

This is a fairly common thing when one is testing different models. For instance, decision trees work well with "Yes" and "No". However some Regression models demands 1 and 0. Particular Logistic Regression.

I solved this by using the plyr library. It was extremely easy and convenient. Here is my solution.

Origin of solution is [here.](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_levels_of_a_factor/)

```
library(plyr)
weather5$RainToday <- revalue(weather5$RainToday, c("Yes"=1))
weather5$RainToday <- revalue(weather5$RainToday, c("No"=0))
head(weather5$RainToday)
[1] 0 1 1 1 1 0
Levels: 0 1
```

Peace!

Comment: "However some Regression models demands 1 and 0" - generally, for most base R statistical procedures you don't need such conversion - your variable is factor so it will be handled properly. You can try it by yourself: `glm(RainToday ~ ., data = weather5, family = binomial)`

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I think my variable wasn't factor before which forced me to convert them into 1 and 0.

Comment: Don't think my variable is factor.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1